# What preposition to use before the word "Mile" in French

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

In French, which preposition would one use before "Mile" would it be dans or à?

I've seen

> Son flair aiguisé lui permet de repérer des restes **à un mile à la ronde.**

but also

> Dans un mile

Comment: Do you have the complete sentence for the second example? I could imagine something like "Dans un mille, nous apercevront le clocher."

Answer (score 2):

Si votre phrase a été extraite de *[ce site](http://emilio-2003.skyrock.com/3251397944-Personnage-Seven-Deadly-Sins.html)*, il s'agit d'une traduction qui a laissé tel quel l'anglais *mile* (1609) mètres dans le texte.

L'ancien français a hérité du *Mille romain* : 1481,5 (soit mille pas), on le retrouve dans les contes.
Il a perdu un `l` et augmenté sa longueur en traversant la manche.

Les marins français utilisent le *mille nautique* de 1852 mètres ; actuellement c'est la distance à laquelle on pense lorsque l'on parle de *mille*.

---

Que l'on évoque *un mile* (à prononcer à l'anglaise) ou *un mille (nautique)* il s'agit d'une distance :

> Une entité est ***à*** une distance **de** quelque chose ou *de* quelqu'un.

***Dans*** un mile... évoque la durée ou l'effort qu'il reste à fournir pour parcourir cette distance.

Comment: D'ailleurs, ne peut-on pas dire en anglais: "We will arrive in 2 kilometers"?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps -- C'est le l'emploi de *dans* *dans* l'espace et *dans* le temps :)

Answer (score 1):

A "mile" is a distance, so you should follow [the general rule](http://french.about.com/library/prepositions/bl_prep_a_vs_de.htm).

> **à** is used in front of the distance, while **de** indicates the starting point/origin

But "Dans un mile" is actually a time implicitely, ("In the time that it takes to travel one mile at our current pace" or "When we'll have traveled one mile")

Answer (score 1):

It is not the noun that define the preposition but the meaning of your sentence. For a "pure" distance you will use "à"

> Notre destination se situe **à** un mille d'ici.

But there can be a lot of cases where the travel (time) is considered and then you have a large number of possible prepositions.

> Nous arriverons **dans** un mille.
>
> Vous devez rouler **pendant** un mille avant d'arriver à votre destination.
>
> Il roulait **depuis** plusieurs milles lorsque c'est arrivé.

Or it could be a complement of the noun, in this case you need "de"

> Nous avons dû faire un détour **de** plusieurs milles à cause de l'effondrement du pont.

Note that "mile" and "mille" both exist in French, but the "one l" version is mainly used in Europe while you will see it written with "two ll's" in America.

Comment: I never saw "mile" written with two "L" and I live in Quebec. It may be different across cities.

Comment: De Wiki: "Le mille terrestre américain et le mille international peuvent s'écrire aussi mile (pluriel miles) en français, mais en aucun cas le mille romain ni le mille marin."